# Ubuntu 15.04 join domain problem (pbis)

Tags: active-directory, 15.04

I just installed a clean Ubuntu 15.04, and I want to join to a domain for active directory.

Downloaded and installed *PBIS Open 8.2.2 - Stable Release* but when i run it:

```
Error: /usr/sbin/service lwsmd start returned 6
Failed to start lwsmd.service: Unit lwsmd.service failed to load: No  such file or directory.

regshell (error = 40700 - LWREG_ERROR_NO_SUCH_KEY_OR_VALUE)
No such key or value 


 Error code: ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (0x00000002)
```

and

```
Backtrace:
/builder/src-buildserver/Platform-8.2/src/linux/domainjoin/domainjoin-gui/gtk/main.c:614
/builder/src-buildserver/Platform-8.2/src/linux/domainjoin/libdomainjoin/src/djapi.c:257
/builder/src-buildserver/Platform-8.2/src/linux/domainjoin/libdomainjoin/src/djroutines.c:54
/builder/src-buildserver/Platform-8.2/src/linux/domainjoin/libdomainjoin/src/djauthinfo.c:1027
```

And when I execute the `domainjoin-cli` it returns me:

```
Error: Received error while querying lwsmd. [code 0x00000002]
```

when I try to execute `/etc/init.d/lwsmd start`, Ubuntu doesn't find it.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to create a systemd unit file for this service, and then enable it. The following worked for me on Ubuntu 15.04 (upgraded from 14.04) with PBIS 8.2.2.

Create the file lwsmd.service in /lib/systemd/system like this:

```
nano /lib/systemd/system/lwsmd.service
```

Here are the contents (paste this in to the file you created above)  (taken from a redhat one) so thanks to them:

```
[Unit]
Description=BeyondTrust PBIS Service Manager
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=/opt/pbis/libexec/init-base.sh
ExecStart=/opt/pbis/sbin/lwsmd --start-as-daemon
ExecReload=/opt/pbis/bin/lwsm refresh
ExecStop=/opt/pbis/bin/lwsm shutdown
# We want systemd to give lwsmd some time to finish gracefully, but still want
# it to kill lwsmd after TimeoutStopSec if something went wrong during the
# graceful stop. Normally, Systemd sends SIGTERM signal right after the
# ExecStop, which would kill lwsmd. We are sending useless SIGCONT here to give
# lwsmd time to finish.
KillSignal=SIGCONT
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target nss-lookup.target
```

Once this is done, make a symlink to this file in /etc/systemd/system:

```
cd /etc/systemd/system
ln -s /lib/systemd/system/lwsmd.service
```

At this point you should be able to type:

```
service lwsmd status
```

and see that the service exists and is enabled.

Then typing:

```
service lwsmd start
```

should start it up and have pbis working as expected.

Now to make it work at boot time. Enable the service with this command:

```
systemctl enable lwsmd.service
```

It should give some feedback about creating some symlinks.

Then reboot your comp and all should be working.

I hope it was clear enough, and please forgive any typos... Good luck!

Comment: This one also worked in Fedora 23 for me

Answer (score 1):

PBIS is not yet installing a service script (startup script) compatible to systemd in ubuntu. You will have to wait fpr pbis guys to fix that or copy the one used for Fedora/Redhat and startup lwsmd before trying to join your domain.

Comment: Any alternative to join a windows domain? Thanks

Comment: There's either a `startup` script or a `systemd` unit.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to kind of work so that domainjoin-cli query would work.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lwsmd restart
sudo domainjoin-cli query
```

Answer (score 0):

Some addition, in */lib/systemd/system/lwsmd.service* you should use

```
PrivateTmp=false
```

Because lwsmd service writes **krb5cc_uid** file for user and computer in */tmp/systemd-private-/some hash/-lwsmd.service/tmp* and other applications (browsers, samba clients) can't find it in */tmp/*

Therefore SSO doesn't work