# Ubuntu 15.10 | Join Active Directory

Tags: xubuntu, 15.10, active-directory, likewise

As I was requested by Pilot6 
I'm attaching the link to the previous question asked:
[How to join Ubuntu 15.04 / 15.10 to Windows domain](https://askubuntu.com/questions/709387/how-to-join-ubuntu-15-04-15-10-to-windows-domain/737309?noredirect=1#comment1095317_737309)

I am on Ubuntu 15.10 and trying to use Likewiseopen to join to active directory.
From what I tried, I've followed the guides to add the service of Lwsmd due to the systemd difference from 14.xx but it doesn't work out,
it keeps failing.
anyone ran into such issue aswell?
Anyone been there and was a pro enough to find a solution?

If so, please share and help me find a solution too.

Thank you all!

Comment: *bump* anyone has any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 15.04 join domain problem (pbis)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/613451/ubuntu-15-04-join-domain-problem-pbis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be a bit late and I'm not sure what you have tried already, but I have worked with PBIS Open myself before and I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my VirtualBox environment to refresh my memory again.

If you get the following error I may know a solution to your problem.
[image: Ubuntu 15.10 PBIS Open lwsmd error]

To solve this, you should check out the answer at the following [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/617070)

I tried it again on my own VirtualBox machine with Ubuntu 15.10 and it worked for me.
[image: success domain join]

So good luck!

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//askubuntu.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, wasn't logged into the account to get any notifications...
Thanks @MadMike, That's something i've already been through.
and yea you have to make a new lwsmd service for it to work (which i did) but its not good enough, it sometimes work and sometimes doesn't when it comes to change password for the domain user\ login for the first time with the domain user it causes way too many glitches until it catches up. 
I finally managed to do so with Centrify free edition upto 200 machines. It works flawlessly (with a tiny delay on the first login)

answer was given though

Comment: Thanks @aviel-corchia but credits should go to Mvsing92,  I only did some editing to make it more readable.

Comment: @MadMike, I've marked the answer as correct in any case, so you both would receive the credit, I believe.

is that ok?

Comment: @AvielCorchia According to this: https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation the points will go to Mvsing92. This 100% okay with me, since relay just made a few corrections as can be seen here: https://askubuntu.com/posts/781724/revisions . :)